# Mounted volume is always empty on container machine on mac/lunux

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to run docker container with some files that I want to share with container machine from the host machine.
For example, I want to share my `~/Desktop` folder with container machine. I am running:

```sh
$ docker run -it -v ~/Desktop:/Desktop r-base bash
```

then when I do `ls -la /Desktop` on container machine it does not show any files even if I have some on my host machine.

When I do `docker inspect <container_id>` it shows my mounts as:

```
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/user/Desktop",
                "Destination": "/Desktop",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

My docker version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
$ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.16.1, build cce350d
```

Comment: Does it work with any other folder?

Comment: @zero298 no - every folder I am trying to share is always empty